# How to assign variables inside Makefile

Tags: variables, makefile

I am trying to set variable with result of grep command inside my Makefile, but it does not work. Is there anything missing here?

```
HOST ?= $(grep HOST ~/.myhostfile)
install:
    ./runInstall.sh ${HOST}
```

I also tried But no success

```
export HOST= $(grep HOST ~/.myhostfile)
```

When I try the same in shell it works fine

Comment: `$(grep ...` --> `$(shell grep ...`.

Comment: great. it worked. Thanks

Comment: Alternatively. Make sure you really pass this onto your shell for Command Substitution by escaping the `$`. I.e.  `$$(grep ...)`.